# Resolve Laravel Auth Authenticatable to User model to address static analysis issues

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, static-analysis, phpstan

We have a Laravel 8 application.

We're using the standard Laravel `Auth` facade to [retrieve the authenticated user](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user).

Our `User` model has a few custom functions, the most important of which is a shorthand function, `hasPermissionTo()`. (The reason why is because we have a very custom RBAC setup.)

So in a lot of our controllers, we have something like this...

```php
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class ExampleController extends BaseController
{

  public function index()
  {
    if (\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Management:View Users')) {
      // do something.
    }
    // etc.
  }
}
```

That's all well and good until we start running static analysis. We're using Larastan, which is giving me these errors:

```
------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Line   Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php
------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  48     Call to an undefined method Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::hasPermissionTo().
```

This also makes sense because the `Auth` facade proxies `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` and `Auth::user()`, via `__call()` magic, normally resolves to `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::user()` and that typehints this...

```php
    /**
     * Get the currently authenticated user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function user()
    {
    ...
```

So finally, my question:

Where is the failure here? Do I need to a) configure my static analysis tool better, b) configure Laravel better to more accurately return a specific type, or c) do I need to add explicit `if (Auth::user() instanceof User) { ... }` clauses all throughout my code?

Is there a *correct* way to override one of the Laravel stock classes with a more specific one of my own to address more specific functionality? Is there way to type-hint the actual authenticated User into the function declaration so I can declare `function index(User $authenticatedUser)` and have Laravel autopopulate this in with a more specific type hint?

I understand that I could just add an exclusion for this particular issue in Larastan and move on with my life, but the error is designed to protect against a specific class of error--i.e. if I added Auth0 and replaced `App\Model\User` with `Auth0\Login\User`, then I would have an `Authenticatable` class that fails to run `hasPermissionTo()`, and I'd have to now fix a bunch of code.

Comment: It’s best to ask this question on Larastan’s GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm not 100% convinced that this is an issue with Larastan, is it?

Comment: @haz did you ever get an answer to this? It seems like this issue is hardly documented anywhere

Comment: @djjavo Sorry, yes, I eventually figured it out! Hopefully this helps you and anyone else coming afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, this is how we worked around the problem. We added a type-hint for Larastan, so it can infer that $user has this `HasRolesContract` trait which provides `hasPermissionTo()`.

```php
  public function index()
  {
        /** @var \App\Traits\HasRolesContract */
        $user = \Auth::user();

        if ($user->hasPermissionTo('Management:View Users')) {
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!

(Thanks for the nudge, @djjavo)